# Differential privacy on Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, frame

Is there a way to implement differential privacy on a Pandas data frame comprising non-numeric entries?  Specifically, if I input the Pandas data frame, can I get a new data frame which is differentially private?

I am aware of a couple of packages for differential privacy, but not sure how to go about it.  Any suggestions/directions shall be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008334/anonymize-specific-columns-with-pii-in-pandas-dataframe-python

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  However, the methods in that link are very ad hoc.  I was looking for a way to implement differential privacy on the pandas data frame.